# pandas, numpy round down to nearest 100

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I created a dataframe column with the below code, and was trying to figure out how to round it down to the nearest 100th.

```
...
# This prints out my new value rounded to the nearest whole number.    
df['new_values'] = (10000/df['old_values']).apply(numpy.floor)

# How do I get it to round down to the nearest 100th instead?
# i.e. 8450 rounded to 8400
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need divide by `100`, convert to `int` and last multiple by `100`:

```
df['new_values'] = (df['old_values'] / 100).astype(int) *100
```

Same as:

```
df['new_values'] = (df['old_values'] / 100).apply(np.floor).astype(int) *100
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'old_values':[8450, 8470, 343, 573, 34543, 23999]})
df['new_values'] = (df['old_values'] / 100).astype(int) *100
print (df)
   old_values  new_values
0        8450        8400
1        8470        8400
2         343         300
3         573         500
4       34543       34500
5       23999       23900
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'old_values':[3, 6, 89, 573, 34, 23]})
#show output of first divide for verifying output
df['new_values1'] = (10000/df['old_values'])
df['new_values'] = (10000/df['old_values']).div(100).astype(int).mul(100)
print (df)
   old_values  new_values1  new_values
0           3  3333.333333        3300
1           6  1666.666667        1600
2          89   112.359551         100
3         573    17.452007           0
4          34   294.117647         200
5          23   434.782609         400
```

Comment: Hello @jezrael, thanks for replying! Originally, my `new_values` is calculated by `10,000 / df['old_values']`. If I were to switch it around, my calculation will be wrong. Do you mean that I need to do my calculations first, before applying your method to round down?

Comment: I am a bit confused, do you think `(df['old_values']/10000)` instead `(10000/df['old_values'])` ?

Comment: Yes, so my `new_values` are obtained by the calculation of `10000/df['old_values']`. The results will definitely be different if I were to do `df['old_values'] / 10000`. Similar with how `2/3` is different from `3/2`. Hope my explanation makes sense?

Comment: I tried this: `df['new_values'] = ((10000 / df['old_values']) / 100).astype(int) * 100`. And when I printed out the dataframe `df['new_values']` it gave me what I wanted. :) (at least based off the first 5 rows)

Comment: Super, I also add it to answer - only sample has to be changed.

Answer (score 7):

Borrowing @jezrael's sample dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'old_values':[8450, 8470, 343, 573, 34543, 23999]})
```

Use `floordiv` or `//`

```
df // 100 * 100

   old_values
0        8400
1        8400
2         300
3         500
4       34500
5       23900
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried something similar using the math module

```
a = [123, 456, 789, 145]

def rdl(x):
ls = []
for i in x:
    a = math.floor(i/100)*100
    ls.append(a)
return ls

rdl(a)
```

`#Output was [100, 200, 400, 700, 100]`

Hope this provides some idea. Its very similar to solution provided by @jezrael